# Why does my custom transition not work with my navigation controller?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, coordinator-pattern

I'm using the coordinator pattern in my code to transition from the RootNavigationController to a SplashScreenViewController

```
class AppCoordinator {
    let window: UIWindow
    let rootViewController: RootNavigationController

    init(window: UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
        rootViewController = RootNavigationController()
        let splashScreenViewController = SplashScreenViewController()

rootViewController.pushViewController(splashScreenViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
extension AppCoordinator: Coordinator {
    func start() {
        window.rootViewController = rootViewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

I'm also using a custom transition to handle the transition from RootNavigationController to SplashScreenNavigationController.

```
class FadeInAnimator: NSObject {
var duration: TimeInterval = 1.0
}
extension FadeInAnimator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return duration
}

func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) else { return }

containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0

let durationOfTransition = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: durationOfTransition, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
        toViewController.view.alpha = 1
    }) { (finished) in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        }
    }
}
```

I've set the delegate of the RootNavigationController to it's self and implemented the animation transitioning however, when I start the application it seems to just ignore everything I've done and just use the systems default transition.

This is the code in the RootNavigationController

```
class RootNavigationController: UINavigationController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delegate = self
    navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
}
extension RootNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    switch operation {
    case .push: return FadeInAnimator()
    case .pop: return nil
    case .none: return nil
    }
}
}
```

Comment: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning is for animating the transition of *modally* presented view controllers. Are you presenting your `SplashScreenViewController` modally, or pushing it onto a navigation controller stack via `pushViewController(_:animated:)`? If you're not sure, share the relevant code from your `RootNavigationController`.

Comment: It is being pushed from a navigation stack as shown in the "AppCoordinator" class

Comment: Sorry, missed that - can you share your RootNavigationController code. Specifically, your implementation of navigationController(_:animationControllerFor:from:to)

Comment: I've edited to show the code in the RootNavigationController

Comment: Try moving the call to pushViewController(_:animated:) out of the AppCoordinator initialiser, and move it into the end of your start() method, after you’ve called makeKeyAndVisible() on the window. Just a theory (hard to be sure without debugging the app myself) - if it works let me know and I’ll write up an answer explaining what’s going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove open & close bracket

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: durationOfTransition, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations:
```

Comment: Can you explain why a bit further?

Comment: may be it's working because [.curveEaseIn] repeat every time so hope so this will work for you